# Wireshark, extract all http headers

Tags: wireshark

I have some `.pcap` from which I would like to extract all http headers.

By using the filters I'm able to display only Http requests but what I would like is to be able to extract/display/print/export the headers for each requests.
Can I do that with Wireshark or should I parse the `.pcap` file myself ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I often do that by using either one of two following options:

1. First option is similar to the one @Elias mentioned earlier, but this is more general, especially when the header field is not visible to select or when you just do not want to look for it in the selected packet.

Go to **Edit - Preferences - Appearance - Column**, on the right hand side, click '**+**' button to define your new column. Name your new column (**Title**), choose Type as "**Custom**" and enter the **Fields** you want to get the information of. Below screenshot is what we have with `http.host` header field.

[image]

2. Second option is to use tshark feature (the tshark.exe file in your Wireshark installtion folder). The below command is to extract the `http.host` header field from http_only pcap file which we used in first option above.

`C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -r http_only.pcapng -T fields -e "http.host" > http_host_only.txt`

[image]

I hope it is useful.

Comment: Yes it is. Especially for `tshark`. However I would like to extract all the http headers (name and maybe value). But I don't know the names..

Comment: You can find all http header fields here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html

and for other protocols here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html

Comment: Sorry. I mean that I don't know in advance the http headers that are in my requests (the goal is to spot uncommon ones). By using `tshark` I'm able to produce a text file that contains all requests and headers separated by an empty line. I think that with a little scripting I should be able to convert them to a csv. (Will update this question)

Comment: Would look forward to it! 

And in case your question is answered, please mark the solution ;).

Comment: Using `tshark -r dump.pcap -i http==1 -O http -T fields -e http.request.method -e http.request.uri -e http.request.line > dump.txt` I have all http requests and headers in a text file. For each request, I have the ´verb path ,first_header\n` followed by all headers on one line and one empty line between each requests. I made a (Scala) script to transform this text file to a csv that we can import into a spreadsheet. Thanks @Hung Tran

Answer (score 4):

If you have a header visible in a selected packet, right click it and choose apply as column. That will add the data as a column to the packet view. Then you can export your filtered data normally to text or any supported format.